# How to make condition between two dates

Tags: android

```
long installed = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.mothistorycheck",0).firstInstallTime;
```

By using this code i am getting app first installed date ,i want to get date after one year from installed date(newDate) and make a condition for current date is less than newDate.not getting how to do it.help me.

Comment: figure out how many milliseconds are in a year and just add that to the current install date, then you have your new date of a year later

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert this long date into a Date object :

```
Date date = new Date(installed*1000L);
```

For current date you can use `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` and then compare the two using Date.after()/Date.before() methods from Date class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test if your time is before the first install time plus a year.  Try this:

```
long installed = context.getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo("com.mothistorycheck",0).firstInstallTime;
Calendar oneYearFromNow = 
    Calendar.getInstance.getDateTime().add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
if(oneYearFromNow.getTimeInMillis())
{
    //do stuff here
}
```